# Why does the listing order of my com ports in a comboBox always change? C#

Tags: c#, combobox, serial-port

I have the problem that my comports always change their order in the list.

I have a `ComboBox` where you can select one of 8 com ports (usb scales) and connect to the selected one. After that, I am saving the the selected index of the `ComboBox` and load it when the form loads next time. But when it is loading it is always listing the ports in an other order, so that the wrong port is selected when `SelectedIndex` is loaded in to the `ComboBox`. How can I solve this?

saving the actual port selected in `ComboBox` :

```
File.WriteAllText("portsave1", textBox18.Text + "+" + comboBox2.SelectedIndex.ToString());
```

on form Load:

```
//Load Com Port List into comboBoxes
string[] portNames = SerialPort.GetPortNames();     //<-- Reads all available comPorts
foreach (var portName in portNames)
{

    comboBox2.Items.Add(portName);                   //<-- Adds Ports to combobox
    comboBox3.Items.Add(portName);
    comboBox5.Items.Add(portName);
    comboBox7.Items.Add(portName);
    comboBox9.Items.Add(portName);
    comboBox12.Items.Add(portName);
    comboBox14.Items.Add(portName);
    comboBox16.Items.Add(portName);
}

if (File.Exists("startstate1"))
{
    checkBox8.Checked = bool.Parse(File.ReadAllText(@"startstate1"));
    if (checkBox8.Checked)
    {
        //Loading the scale name and com ports Scale1 / TAB 1
        if (File.Exists("portsave1"))
        {
            StreamReader sr2 = new StreamReader("portsave1");
            string portload = sr2.ReadToEnd();


            String[] portstrings1 = portload.Split(new string[] { "+" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
            if (portstrings1[0] != string.Empty)
            {
                textBox18.Text = portstrings1[0];
                tabPage1.Text = portstrings1[0];
                button13.Text = portstrings1[0];
            }
            int comport = Convert.ToInt32(portstrings1[1]);

            try
            {
                comboBox2.SelectedIndex = comport;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ein gespeicherter Port ist nicht mehr vorhanden", "Information",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                comboBox2.ResetText();
            }
            sr2.Close();
        }
        //connect to the scale on the port loaded into comboBox
        button1_Click(null, null);
    }
}
```

I hope someone can help me. Thank you.

Comment: Instead of saving the index, save the COM name... You don't know if the system has changed the COM order, removed one element or whatsoever.

Comment: But how do you fill that comboBox2? Please add this code to have a better idea of your problem

Comment: I have edited my question, now you can see how the comboBoxes where filled on start...

Comment: how do I load the portname into the comboBox on start? comboBox.selectedIndex = portname-xy ?

Comment: I think you can load the combobox as you already are and then just set the `SelectedValue` property to the port name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, Thank you at all, I solved the problem. All your Code is correct and there are many way's, like comboBox.Text, comboBox.Item to save that.... My problem was that, I saved it twice, once after connecting to the scale and once when the Form is closing... And when Form was closing it wrote the selected index into the file so that is why it couldn't work.  I didn't noticed that and was wondering why its not working. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Don't select your data using an index stored from a previous session.**

You need to change how you are setting the selecting data in your combobox since index is unreliable between sessions. Instead you should look for a match for the text you desire and have that selected.

Instead of:

```
int comport = Convert.ToInt32(portstrings1[1]);
comboBox2.SelectedIndex = comport;
```

use this:

```
string comport = portstrings1[1];
comboBox2.SelectedIndex = comboBox2.FindStringExact(comport);
```

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c440x2eb(v=vs.110).aspx) on the method `FindStringExact`.

> Finds the first item in the combo box that matches the specified
>   string.

In order for this to work you will need to modify how you are saving the selected data. Save the selected text value of the combobox instead of the index.

```
File.WriteAllText("portsave1", textBox18.Text + "+" + comboBox2.Text);
```

---

**Bonus Note:**

You should *really* consider using more verbose naming conventions for your controls which you are accessing via code. combobox2 doesn't mean much. A name like comboboxUSBScalePort makes your code more readable and will make future maintenance a lot easier.

Remember, the point of code is to be *human* readable.

Comment: Hello, I dont know why, but Its not working, when I load the Form, the ComboBox stays empty. But your code should work I think... What could be wrong? I fill the combobox with ports on form load...

Comment: OK, now I know what the problem is!
When I save comboBox2.SelectedText then it saves only an empty string, not the text that is displayed in the ComboBox (COM1). Why does this happen?

Comment: Is it maybe because a COM Port is not a Text but an Item?

Comment: Change `.SelectedText` to `.Text`